# Linux user group permissions and virtual development environments

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

So, I wanted to establish a virtual development environment that would be shared by a few users for collaboration.

I created a new user group X denoting the group of users allowed access the virtual development environment.
Then, I added two users to this group.
Following that, I created the directory in /usr/share/X
I modified the group of X with chgrp and changed it to the group I created.
I then did chmod -R g+rwx X
Unfortunately, these two users find they still need to sudo to create directories and files within this directory.
If I use chown I can own it for a specific user, but that's not what I want. I want it to be owned by the group.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I searched the web for awhile and couldn't find anything that directly addresses this problem directly, and I could not figure it out from the available information.

Thanks.

Comment: as a side note I tried sudo chown -R X (dir)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't restart the bash shell after I added myself to the new group that owns the directory, so I was operating in a bash shell as myself without the group I appended to my user.

I had no idea that I needed to restart bash after adding myself to a user group. That's important to know haha.

Comment: It's not about restarting bash, technically. It's about having bash started *by a privileged process* (e.g. `su` or the login manager) which re-reads /etc/group before starting bash.